# How to share a Google+ public post outside of the Google+ app?

Tags: google-plus, share-menu

Most apps share their content out to other apps based on intents on the phone. The Google+ app's share feature only seems to generate another Google+ post. How can I share a  Google+ public post outside of the app from the app itself? For example, to send a link of the post to Twitter, Messenger, Facebook, etc.

I can't believe Google would cauterize sharing from a service as important to them as Google+ when most other popular social apps can share freely among each other. Copy & paste of the URL is dated and onerous on Android.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Tap the post you want to share
2. Open the overflow menu (three vertical dots)
3. Tap "Link"

   - You'll receive a message: "Post link copied to clipboard."
4. You can now paste that link to whatever sharing mechanism you'd like

Not the same as using the Android Share function, but, again, Google+ is not alone in doing this. I don't know when this function was added to the G+ app.

Of course, it only works for Public posts.

Comment: Excellent news, thank you.  It's worth noting this technique only works on public posts, as it should.

Answer (score 2):

**The simple answer**

You cannot.

**Expanded Answer**

The share button on Google+ posts in the app is called the 'resharing' button - it is just like retweeting on twitter (as most people probably know).

There is currently no way to share Google+ content to other Social Networking/Messaging/Chat apps etc - this is by design of the app, and cannot be changed.

The only way to do this would be to ask Google to implement this feature, or to decompile the app and add it yourself (which would be obviously *very* difficult).

**The Conclusion**

So, I know that this isn't what you wanted to hear, but I am afraid that no-one will be able to give you a 'correct' answer to this question, as there is no way to share Google+ content outside Google+ using the Google+ application.

Comment: Thank you. It's a shame, that fact, because that limitation makes me shy away from G+ on my mobile device in favour of other services in which sharing of content is more open and easy. Even with the official Twitter mobile client I can share out to many other services in addition to simply retweeting.

Comment: One thing I've found since making this post and assigning a bounty is that G+ Public posts aren't visible unless user's are logged into their Google account through a Google service like Gmail, Google+, etc.  So in a way, there's the question of: why *would* a user want to share out a public G+ post when it's still behind the Google wall in a way, and not necessarily immediately accessible to the masses from other platforms.

Comment: While it may be difficult to share a "post" (including comments), sharing the URL of a link which was posted should be relatively easy: a simple way to achieve this is to have an app which appears like a web-browser (and thus appears in the "open with" menu when you tap to open a link), and then automatically opens a "share with" menu using this link as the content to be shared (just as if it were a URL "shared" from a web-browser app).  I haven't found such an app yet, but making one would be straightforward. (yes, this can be done slowly by opening link in browser / then sharing)

Answer (score 1):

In order to share a *link* from Google+ (not a link to a G+ post, but a link shared from a post), you can use an app which appears as a web-browser, and then passes the URL on as a share intent, opening the share menu.

I described this in my comment on Liam W's answer, and finally did find an app that does what I described, called [Browser Intercept - Share URL](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intrications.android.sharebrowser).  Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

As everyone stated, this is a feature inexplicably missing in the google+ app.
(If I were Vic I would have resigned in shame too)

Google+ only *copies the link to the clipboard*.

But we can use [Clipboard manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.rojekti.clipper&hl=en) to **share the content of the clipping to other applications**.

[image]

And you can be notified when a link is copied to the clipboard:

[image]